# unable to resize images using sharp

Tags: node.js, multer, sharp

I am using multer to upload images to the server . And i am using sharp to resize the images and then send to the client. But what happens is once a user uploads the image, multer uploads it to the server and sharp resizes it even but if the same user uploads again multer uploads the new file but sharp doesnt resize the new uploaded image rather it sends the original resized image.

```
app.post('/upload',(req,res)=>{
    upload(req,res,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.render('picupload',{
                msg: err
            });
        }else{
           if(req.file == undefined){
               res.render('picupload',{
                   msg: 'Error: No File selected!'
               });
           } else{
            console.log(req.file);
            sharp(`./public/uploads/${req.file.filename}`)
                .resize(40,40)
                .toFile(`./public/uploads/resize/${req.file.filename}`,(err,info)=>{
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log(info);
                });

            res.render(pathjoin13,{
                file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}` ,
                file1: `uploads/resize/${req.file.filename}`
            });
           }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `res.render()` call depends on the output of the asynchronous `toFile()` call so will need to move to its callback, something like:

```
.toFile(`./public/uploads/resize/${req.file.filename}`,(err,info)=>{
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(info);

  res.render(pathjoin13,{
    file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}` ,
    file1: `uploads/resize/${req.file.filename}`
  });
});
```

Comment: Will that make a difference? If that's the case then when a user uploads a picture it shouldn't resize it at all in the first case coz by the time it resizess res.render function is call owing to the async .toFile method. But what happens is when a new user uploads a picture it resizes it and i send the resized image to the client, but when again the same user uploads a new image, sharp doesn't resize it, instead it renders the old resized image.